# Toggle between two functions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I tried making a button toggle between two functions but I can't get it to work. Could you guys tell me why?

```
function a(el) {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%"; 
}

function b(el) {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}

$("menubutton").click(function() { 
  return (this.tog = !this.tog) ? a() : b();
});
```

It's supposed to open/close the navigation but it does nothing at all :/

Comment: Your selector is wrong, it's looking for a `<menubutton />` element which is invalid. Presumably this should be `$("#menubutton")` or `$(".menubutton")`. Once you fix that your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/d9k8yr4h/. Voting to close as a typo. Also note that you can make the code much simpler (and follow better practice) by toggling a class on the `#myDiv` element: https://jsfiddle.net/d9k8yr4h/1/

Comment: What is this.tog supposed to be? It would generally be better to handle this via two different css classes and just use `toggleclass('class1 class2')`. Separate markup, css and JavaScript.

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to hide "myNav". If so, you can do it with $("#myNav").fadeToggle(); And as said in the first comment, your selector is wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. 
Anyway, if I get your requirements (i.e. jus toggling the visibility of the myNav component), and supposing menubutton is the ID of a button:

```
$("#menubutton").click(function() {
 $("#myNav").toggle();

});
```

See specs:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Instead, you you need a show function and an hide function for your components, to reuse somewhere else, you can use `$("#myNav").show()` or `$("#myNav").hide()`

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit long to explain why but they way I wanted to it doesn't work with toggleClass. 
Anyway, Rory McRossan (first comment under my question) found the solution it was just a typo. I was pretty sure I tried this solution but I obviously didn't. Thank you Rory